# Accessing Private Web Services from iPhone app

Tags: iphone, asp.net, ios, web-services

We have our website hosted on external data center and it interacts with various asp.net web services hosted on in-house servers. For security reasons, we have blocked public access to these web services and only external data center where website is hosted has access.

Now we are creating a iPhone app for the website and I'm wondering how we can access these private web services from the app which are downloaded to users' phones. Do we need to create a middle ware layer to accommodate the communication between iPhone app and the private web services? Or is there a better solution.

Comment: I guess you'll have to use that middle ware layer. The data center is considered local, so the only way without that middle ware thing is to enable public access, which will simply ruin your security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phoenix,

Unfortunately for this type of application you need to create an intermediary layer. To do this you can create APIs with .Net to respond the calls required, resulting in an XML file and / or JSON that is perfectly interpreted by iOS frameworks. I thing that it is the best way.

Good Lucky